# DIV Card misplacing in another row

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, containers

[image: This is how it currently looks]

I am trying to get my div card to stay right next to my other card board and also dont get strached out. The first one works perfectly, but I dont know how to place the next one right next to the first one...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM beitrag WHERE beitrag_id=97 OR beitrag_id=98";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {

$beitrag = "    
    <div class='pagecontainer'>
        <div class='container'>
        <div class='jumbotron p- p-md-5 text-white rounded bg-dark'>
        <div class='col-md-6 px-0'>
        <h1 class='display-4 font-italic'>Student, Azubi, FSJler, Schüler...?</h1>
        <p class='lead my-3'>Tauschen Sie sich noch heute mit tausenden Gleichgesinnten über Ihre finanzielle Planung aus!</p>
        <p class='lead mb-0'><a href='beitraege.php' class='text-white font-weight-bold'>Ab zu den Beitraegen!</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row mb-2'>";


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $beitrag_id = $row['beitrag_id'];
        $titel = $row['titel'];
        $miete = $row['miete'];
        $einkauf = $row['einkauf'];
        $freizeit = $row['freizeit'];
        $sonstiges = $row['sonstiges'];
        $g_kosten = $row['g_kosten'];
        $p_text = $row['p_text'];

$beitrag .="
    <div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='card' style=''>               
    <div class='card-body'>         
    <h4 class='card-title'>$titel</h4>          
    <p class='card-text'>$p_text</p>            
    <a href='siehe_beitrag.php?pid=$beitrag_id' class='btn btn-primary'>Mehr erfahren</a>         
    </div>      
    </div>
";

$beitrag .="
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

";
    }
    echo $beitrag;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code istead of yours.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM beitrag WHERE beitrag_id=97 OR beitrag_id=98";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {

$beitrag = "    
    <div class='pagecontainer'>
        <div class='container'>
        <div class='jumbotron p- p-md-5 text-white rounded bg-dark'>
        <div class='col-md-6 px-0'>
        <h1 class='display-4 font-italic'>Student, Azubi, FSJler, Schüler...?</h1>
        <p class='lead my-3'>Tauschen Sie sich noch heute mit tausenden Gleichgesinnten über Ihre finanzielle Planung aus!</p>
        <p class='lead mb-0'><a href='beitraege.php' class='text-white font-weight-bold'>Ab zu den Beitraegen!</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row mb-2'>";


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $beitrag_id = $row['beitrag_id'];
        $titel = $row['titel'];
        $miete = $row['miete'];
        $einkauf = $row['einkauf'];
        $freizeit = $row['freizeit'];
        $sonstiges = $row['sonstiges'];
        $g_kosten = $row['g_kosten'];
        $p_text = $row['p_text'];

$beitrag .="
    <div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='card' style=''>               
    <div class='card-body'>         
    <h4 class='card-title'>$titel</h4>          
    <p class='card-text'>$p_text</p>            
    <a href='siehe_beitrag.php?pid=$beitrag_id' class='btn btn-primary'>Mehr erfahren</a>         
    </div>      
    </div>
</div>
";

//you fault here. You should have the loop on this card only.
    }

//you fault here. one </div> goes down bottom.
$beitrag .="

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

";
    echo $beitrag;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried out your code, unfortunately it did not change anything...

Comment: Just for sure, Isnt the image was your output? https://imgur.com/a/kuZWETz

Comment: Yes that is how it supposed to look. If you try your code out, it looks like on the picture?

Comment: Yeah, the avobe code gives me this output. just cpy my code and paste it to your desire place.

Comment: can you show me the rendered html from source? you can use jsfiddle for that, or imgur.

Comment: Yes but no.
actually I want to see only  `<div class='pagecontainer'>...</div>` portion in detail.

Comment: oh okay, hope that works better: https://jsfiddle.net/lancebbb/eyhtknsa/

Comment: I found the problem. wait updating my answer.

Comment: I have not your database. and any database connection. thats why i tried by manual. you should say, any more issues or not!

Comment: Hi **@Tatsächlich ** if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.